# How to fix "no operator " != " matches these operands"?

Tags: c++, stream, binary, fstream, ifstream

When I ran the below program, it gave me an error:

> no operator "!=" matches these operands

The error line is `while (infile.get(ch) != 0)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "\nFormat:otype filename";
        exit(-1);
    }
    char ch;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    if (!infile)
    {
        cerr << "\nCan't open " << argv[1];
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (infile.get(ch) != 0)
        cout << ch;
}
```

Comment: Look at what `get` returns: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: To fix that ,you can simply write `while (infile.get(ch))` instead.

Comment: I did man . thanks anyway

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
while (infile)
{
    infile.get(ch);
    cout << ch;
}
```

I solved with this way

and

```
while (infile.get(ch))
cout<<ch;
```

this way.

Comment: The first way is still wrong, since the result of `get()` is not being validated to ensure `ch` is ok to use.  The second way does that validation, use that way instead.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. You are right. I was inexperienced when I asked this question but now, I understand why that way is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[`istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns an `isteam&` reference to the stream itself.  `istream` does not implement any `operator!=`, let alone one that takes an `int` ass input, which is why you are getting the error.

`istream` does, however, implement a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that you can use directly in the `if`.  That operator returns `true` (or, prior to C++11, a non-null `void*` pointer) if the stream is not in an error state.  So you can change the `while` statement to the following instead:

```cpp
while (infile.get(ch))
    cout << ch;
```